# Sort Mysql data by nearest date compare to current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I want to sort data by the earliest date compare to the current date. Like - Now 8 April, so the nearest data from the screenshot is ID 5 (9 April) and then ID 4 (28 April).
My expected outcome will - be ID 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 Data will save randomly in the database table. I am using MySQL.  Is there any SQL query for this?

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHnlP.png)

Thanks

Comment: can you post the query you are making?

Comment: Select * From `events`(table name) order by [nearest date to current date] @JavierG.Raya

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to get the number of days away from today, as well as [`ABS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) to get the exact difference instead of a positive/negative number

```
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), create_at))
```

This chart shows what the differences will use to sort

```
+------------+----------+----------+
| date       | datediff | with_abs |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 2022-03-24 |       14 |       14 |
| 2022-04-09 |       -2 |        2 |
| 2022-04-24 |      -17 |       17 |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Almost close to my expected outcome. Can I select the upcoming nearest date data? I mean now is April, so April, May, June date data and then passed date data like clockwise. April, May... Feb, March

Comment: Working solution, just would avoid `ABS` as this will break the correct order by nearest date - OP needs the earliest date in the future. Anyway, +1

Comment: DATEDIFF returns the number of days between now and the selected date. If it's in the past, DATEDIFF returns a positive number, if the date is in the future, then it returns a negative number. ABS will turn that into an absolute number, so a date of 2022-04-01 would be 6 either way, but 2022-04-21 will be -14 without the ABS, and 14 with the ABS.